# App version IOS 7 & IOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, ios7, ios9

I have developped an Iphone app with Swift 2 which I have recently migrated to Swift 3.  The Swift 2 version was compatible from IOS 7.0, while the new version developped with Swift 3 is compatible from IOS 9.0

Can we have both versions (the one developped with Swift 2 and Swift 3) operative (live together) in the APP store?

This way, anybody with IOS 7.0 & IOS 8.0 can use the old application, while people who have IOS 9 & IOS 10 can use the new aplication.

Can both applications live together?  How?

Comment: Make another app in iTunes Connect and use different bundle identifiers.

Comment: While this would work, it can cause end user confusion.  Also, the old app users would be unable to simply upgrade the app if you created a new app / bundle ID for the Swift 3 version of the app.  If you did this, I would update the existing app to swift 3, only supporting iOS 8+. Existing users would either upgrade if they are iOS 8+, or keep their existing app if they aren't eligible for updating.  Then if you really need to support iOS 7 (doubtful), you could create a new version of the app with a new bundle ID for new users who are still on iOS 7.  Wouldn't recommend this approach, though.

Answer (score 1):

Go to itunesconnect, go to your app, go to the App Store tab, and click Pricing & Availability.  At the bottom is a section that says Last-Compatible Version Setting.  Click the 'available versions' link and you'll be taken to a page where you can control which versions are available to people with older iOS versions, etc.  In other words, you can have both versions available.  You'll have your "main" one, which will be the most recent, but people with older phones can still download your old iOS 7.0 version.

Comment: This is true and is the correct answer, but it should be noted that you will be unable to update the old, Swift 2 / iOS7 support version.  It will live on and can be installed by iOS 7 users (they will get prompted if they try to install your app in iOS 7).  But if you make any backend changes that require an app update, you can't update, build, and elevate the old app to the App Store any more.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 can be used for iOS 8 and later. You can't support iOS 7 with an app built with Swift 3.

There is little reason for you to keep supporting iOS 7. Just put out an app update with support for iOS 8 and later and the few existing users on iOS 7 can keep using the old version of your app.

There is no way to have two versions of your app in the App Store. You could keep the old Swift 2.3 version in the store and post the new Swift 3 version as a new app. But none of your existing users would know to download and install the new app.